# Problem with the output of a synchronous non-inverting buck-boost converter

Tags: arduino, mosfet, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, gate-driving

I found this electronic circuit in an old research, along with the code necessary to operate it. When I applied it in the laboratory, the results were not the same as in the original research, not even close. The voltage on the capacitor is equal to the battery voltage, and this is what I do not want. This "synchronous non-inverting buck-boost converter" must output a voltage higher than approximately 13.5 to charge the 12 V 7 Ah battery. The primary source for this circuit is a 50 W solar panel. I have checked all the parts, connections, and even the code, and I still do not know the reason. If this converter does not work, I suspect the reason may be the MOSFET gate driver connections. I tried to contact the person who did this research, but unfortunately, I did not find any email for him. What are your suggestions?

[image]

I fixed the position of the capacitors and I made my power supply "solar panel" at 17 V, and it started giving me 13-14.5 V at the output of the converter but it's not stable and the input of gates for left MOSFETs "buck leg" will be like the picture below, how can I fix it?
[image]

The Arduino code is generating 10 kHz signals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it can't work because the gate driver schematics have an error.

Capacitors C2 and C4 are not correctly connected.

Please fix it by reading the IR2104 data sheet for examples.

Comment: A more complete answer would include the error you've found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what are your recommendations in this regard?

Comment: this is the datasheet for MOSFET gate driver: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7c1c31671

Comment: *Justme* says the caps \$C_2\$ and \$C_4\$ are not properly connected because their low-side connection should return to the VS pin of their respective circuit, not ground. Let me know if you want a quick sketch in an answer. Besides, I would not recommend a 1N4148 for this bootstrap section but rather a stronger diode, perhaps a UF4002 (I don't know the input voltage) in series with a small 10-Ohm resistance.

Comment: both of the MOSFET drivers get their Vcc from the battery that I want to charge, and the converter starts charging the battery when it reaches 11.3 v and stops when reaching 14 v, so you recommend me to change the diode ?,