# Boost mode doesn’t work properly for a syncronous non-inverting buck-boost converter

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost, mppt

I posted [a related question 5 days ago.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691793/problem-with-the-output-of-a-synchronous-non-inverting-buck-boost-converter) I fixed the capacitor position the same as the datasheet recommendation of the gate driver by making it connect Vb with Vs, also the one who answered my question and recommended me to change it, and the converter started working but only worked for buck mode not in boost mode.  I also get a high spike value on the first MOSFET gate. I spent so much time to check every detail at this circuit and can't find any problem either in connections or component.

Can anyone help me find what I should do to make boost mode work and get rid of the spikes?

If anyone wants the original research with code, just send me your e-mail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the board? Why no decoupling caps on the input?

Comment: how much value for a capacitor is needed, my maximum input is 20v, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Depends on current and switching frequency, but for a 50W panel you're expecting 4A at least so a bunch of 10µF MLCCs at least... I see a 1mH inductor, that's a huge value, what inductor did you use?

Comment: thanks for your response, I used a variable inductor at my college laboratory but I have a small 3mh inductor and always plug it into my circuit, and Arduino frequency is 10KHZ, but do you have an idea why I can't get boost mode from this circuit.

Comment: How would I know? You haven't posted pics of the circuit or any other information. But if you describe a 1mH inductor for >5A as "small" it's probably one of the issues...